# Manipulation of UserControl event / properties / method / enum etc. in Winform application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio

I have 200+ UserControls on `form1.cs` (Winforms application) and confuse between event / method / properties  and  enum of each UserControls which are not in proper order in `form1.cs` coding page.

I can order them by manually like set comment like `//` and by provide identity manually.

I want to know is there a different way to handle them by a specific method or any other way?

**For Example:**

```
namespace FinApps
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private FinAppsUserControl.ExportReports er;
    private FinAppsUserControl.BankMaster bankmaster;
    private FinAppsUserControl.CompanyMaster companymaster;

    public Form1()
    {
        er = new FinAppsUserControl.ExportReports();
        bankmaster = new FinAppsUserControl.BankMaster();
        companymaster = new FinAppsUserControl.CompanyMaster();

        InitializeComponent();

        this.panel2.Controls.Add(er);
        this.panel2.Controls.Add(bankmaster);
        this.panel2.Controls.Add(companymaster);

      bankmaster.BankMasterExitEvent += new FinAppsUserControl.BankMaster.bankmasterexitevent(bankmaster_BankMasterExitEvent);
        er.ExportReportsKeyDownEvent += new FinAppsUserControl.ExportReports.exportreportskeydownevent(er_ExportReportsKeyDownEvent);
        companymaster.CloseEvent += new FinAppsUserControl.CompanyMaster.closeevent(companymaster_CloseEvent);
     }


//below is mix event/properties/method not sorted by specific UserControl Order..

    private void er_ExportReportsKeyDownEvent(ref Message msg, Keys keydata)
    {
        if (keydata == Keys.Escape) 
        {
        // specific tasks          
        }
    }
 private void bankmaster_BankMasterExitEvent()
 {
      //specific tasks
 }

 private void companymaster_CloseEvent()
 {
        //specific tasks
 }
```

but I want to sort event/method/properties of Specific UserControl vide specific Usercontrol vise like below which I manually adjusted.

```
    //ExportReportUserControl
    private void er_ExportReportsKeyDownEvent(ref Message msg, Keys keydata)
    {
        if (keydata == Keys.Escape) 
        {
        // specific tasks          
        }
    }

   //BankMasterUserControl
 private void bankmaster_BankMasterExitEvent()
 {
      //specific tasks
 }

  //CompanyMasterUserControl

 private void companymaster_CloseEvent()
 {
        //specific tasks
 }
```

The above example are related to only three UserControl and there may about 200+ UserControls and each UserControls may be contain more Event/Method/Properties and Enum on Form1.cs coding page. I just want to sort them by specific UserControl Idenetity which I have manually declared above by comment `//`.

So my idea about to declare a specific method in **form1.cs** which is related to specific UserControls which contain individually their event/method/properties/enum and thus we can easily solve the above confusion.

Is it possible?. Or any other better way?.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish, can you be more specific?

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick, what you want to know about my question I can provide it.

Comment: Be more specific about what are you asking for?

Comment: Any thought that you may have too many controls on one form? You may want to group sets of controls together in larget controlls containing the smaller ones. That would also help to organize the event handling code.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, Do you have any example for your suggestion?. If yes than please furnish. Which would help our new comer community member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use #region - #endregion tags, for example:

```
#region MyUserControl1 things

//Put your MyUserControl1 methods, event handlers etc. here

#endregion

#region MyUserContro2 things

//Put your MyUserContro2 methods, event handlers etc. here

#endregion
```